# Unable to open a URL when an app launch in React Native

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, push-notification, deep-linking

Here is what I am doing:
As a user clicks on push notification, I am creating a link which is handled by MyApp via deep linking to navigate to a specific screen. E.g.

- Push notification is received
- An ACTION_VIEW `Intent` is created and passed to the `PendingIntent`
- User taps the notification
- User is navigated to a specific screen

It is working very well when the app is on foreground. But the problem is, when I am opening a URL when application is launched from notification tap, it doesn't work. Specifically, the `startActivity(intent)` part. I can see the logs in logcat but URL is not being opened. Below is the code which is getting the data from push notification and creating a URL.

```java
package com.myapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;


import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
    final String TAG = "MAIN";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(null);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        final String tenantId = i.getStringExtra("tenantId");
        if (tenantId != null) {
            String uriString = BuildConfig.URL_SCHEME + "://tenant/" + tenantId;
            Log.d(TAG, uriString);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }

   
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "myapp";
    }
}
```

Please help me if I am missing something or doing something wrong. Your input would be appreciated. Thanks.

P.S. Does this `android:launchMode="singleTask"` has to do something with what I want?